# How to turn off single quote escaping in PostgreSQL using Sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

Building a REST API in Node/Express and having difficulty with the generated SQL - specifically, the way it escapes single quotes. When I copied the query into PostgreSQL manually, removing the escape slashes, it ran fine. Is this a setting I can turn off, either in my `config.json`, migrations, or models?

```
   { name: 'error',
     length: 104,
     severity: 'ERROR',
     code: '42P01',
     position: '13',
     file: 'parse_relation.c',
     line: '1180',
     routine: 'parserOpenTable',
     sql: 'INSERT INTO "Users" ("id","email","password","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,\'Shepard@n7.gov\',\'$2a$10$PINeuopaJc6B/kbabnqAM.FCD/nr76/PC3jVjlonAuefptXMvswIO\',\'2019-02-15 17:53:26.329 +00:00\',\'2019-02-15 17:53:26.329 +00:00\') RETURNING *;' }
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I was chasing the wrong thread; the database's ability to take the non-escaped values in the clause wasn't relevant. The problem was that my migration was generated with a table name that violated the PostgreSQL naming convention; when I corrected this (I had a capitalized first letter in my table name, so I edited the migration for a lowercase first letter and reran it), the error disappeared.